# Rename column in mysql (failed)

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl, alter

I have a database (some) with a table (exp) of over 800 records, I want to change the name of a column from "Nr._CRT" to "ID", keeping the type smallint.
Error is :

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '._CRT to ID' at line 1
```

So far I have tried the following

```
    ALTER TABLE exp change Nr._CRT ID ;
    ALTER TABLE exp change 'Nr._CRT' 'ID' ;
    ALTER TABLE exp RENAME COLUMN Nr._CRT TO ID;
    ALTER TABLE exp RENAME COLUMN 'Nr._CRT' TO 'ID';
    ALTER TABLE exp CHANGE Nr._CRT ID ;
    ALTER TABLE exp CHANGE 'Nr._CRT' 'ID' ;
    ALTER TABLE exp RENAME COLUMN Nr._CRT TO ID;
    ALTER TABLE exp RENAME COLUMN 'Nr._CRT' TO 'ID';
```

Any help please ...

Comment: ALTER TABLE "table_name"
RENAME COLUMN "column 1" TO "column 2";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the statements in your list are valid MySQL syntax. The problem is how to properly quote the original column name, that contains special characters: you need backticks rather than single quotes (which are meant for litteral strings, not for identifiers).

For example:

```
ALTER TABLE exp RENAME COLUMN `Nr._CRT` TO id;
```